# Multidomain and document root on a single shared server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, domain, documentroot

I have a website on a shared server with a domain like aaa.com

Its document root is by default "/www" folder.

...

I have a second site with a domain like bbb.com

I checked multidomain on the hosting manager.

I put the website in a "/wwww" folder, to not mix the two websites.

I indicated the document root "/wwww" on the hosting manager.

But bbb.com returns "500 Internal Server Error".

...

Any idea of why? I can't have several root for my several websites?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting support helped me, I had a problem with 2 .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can ... as long as it is configured properly.

You have not included the main httpd.conf, so posters will be unable to effectively help you.

One question is that does www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com point to the same system; do they have different IP numbers;  is your system configured to handle the two IP numbers?

There are really lots of questions here.

Comment: I haven't httpd.conf, it's a shared hosting.